# Can anyone tell me why i am getting the error 'Cannot read property 'value' of undefined'? P5.JS

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, p5.js

I am coding a drawing app in which i am using constructor functions , my code is to try to get a hexagon to appear as a drawing tool. My issue is when i was trying to link it to another constructor function, it gives me the error

```
    Hexagon.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at HexagonTool.draw (Hexagon.js:27)
    at draw (sketch.js:53)
    at e.d.redraw (p5.min.js:32)
    at e.<anonymous> (p5.min.js:31)
```

Does .value() not work as a constructor function? my code is split so all constructor functions are separate which link into a sketch and html file, i can post more code of other areas to help figure it out if need be. The code is below:

```js
function HexagonTool() {
  //set an icon and a name for the object
  this.icon = "assets/shapes.jpg";
  this.name = "shapes";

  var Hexagon;
  var HexagonSize;

  var HexagonSizeSlider;
  var nHexagonSlider;

  function preload() {
    Hexagon = loadImage('assets/Hexagon.png');
  }

  function setup() {
    HexagonSizeSlider = createSlider(5, 60, 20);
    HexagonSizeSlider.parent("#sizeOfHexagonControl");

    nHexagonSlider = createSlider(1, 25, 5);
    nHexagonSlider.parent("#numberOfHexagonsControl");
  }

  this.draw = function() {

    if (mouseIsPressed) {
      for (var i = 0; i < nHexagonSlider.value(); i++) {
        var HexagonSize = HexagonSizeSlider.value();
        var HexagonX = random((mouseX - HexagonSize / 2) - 25, (mouseX - HexagonSize / 2) + 25);
        var HexagonY = random((mouseY - HexagonSize / 2) - 25, (mouseY - HexagonSize / 2) + 25);
        image(Hexagon, HexagonX, HexagonY, HexagonSize,
          HexagonSize);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `setup()` is never called.

Comment: hey when do preload() and setup() get executed? I see you defined them, but did you call them somewhere before using nHexagonSolider?

Comment: @ChrisG is right, the p5 functions like setup() shouldn't be nested inside your larger function HexagonTool() since the interior functions will only be accessible from the interior scope. I tried it out on https://editor.p5js.org/ and it worked without HexagonTool()

Comment: @ChrisG I am looking at it, and this is after a few hours of trying to get it to work, i had two copies of preload and, removing the setup in the code above solved it, so thank you for that,         a question though, i can change the size of the shape using my slider, but it does not allow me to change the amount of shapes via the slider, any ideas?

Comment: No clue, sorry, can you create a [mre]?

Comment: @ChrisG As i was trying to recreate the problem, I managed to solve it by removing a variable on a separate file of code. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at it, and this is after a few hours of trying to get it to work, i had two copies of preload and, removing the setup in the code above solved it